# Text existence of covariant property without generating AmbiguousMatchException

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection, covariant-return-types

My base view model uses `Type.GetProperty` to verify that a given property (for which we are about to raise `PropertyChanged`) actually exists in the class.

It works great.   But if you test for the existence of a property that you have overridden with a more derived type (ie.a covariant return types), an `AmbiguousMatchException` is generated.   I can catch and avoid this but I would like to silence it.  It makes my debugging experience more noisy.

Is there an alternate or more-specific way to test for the existence of such a property and NOT get an `AmbiguousMatchException`?

Here is an oversimplified version of the base view model.

```
public abstract class Observable  : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        try
        {
            if (null == type.GetProperty(propertyName)
                 Debug.Fail($"{propertyName} is not a public property of {type.FullName}");
            else
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        catch(AmbiguousMatchException)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

And here are some classes (deliberately stripped-down) that use covariant return types to on a property.

When I check for the existence of the "Geometry" property in the base class, I get the exception

```
public abstract class Shape  : Observable { public abstract Geometry        Geometry { get; } }
public          class Circle : Shape      { public          EllipseGeometry Geometry { get; } }
public          class Line   : Shape      { public          LineGeometry    Geometry { get; } }
```

Comment: When I'm looking for a particularl overload of a class' methods, I use `GetMethods` (rather than `GetMethod`) then filter it down by method name and other method properties (something like "the generic method named 'xyz' with two arguments"). Have you tried something like that

Comment: Ah, there *is* a `GetProperties` method.  I think I looked right at it and didn't see it.  A bit more expensive but totally worth since this only compiles in Debug mode anyway.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how much more expensive it is.  `GetProperty(string name)` is probably implememented as `GetProperties()?.Where(p => p.Name == name);` or something like that.